# Test method call with different arguments in PHPUnit

Tags: mocking, phpunit

I have the following abstract class:

```
abstract class Voter
{
    public function vote()
    {
        $this->something();
        $this->something();

        $this->voteFoo();
        $this->voteBar();
    }

    public function __call($method, $args)
    {
        //...
    }

    abstract public function something();
}
```

`voteFoo` and `voteBar` are handled by `__call`.

I want to assert that `vote()` calls both `voteFoo()` and `voteBar()`, how can I do that?

I tried using `$this->at(..)` but it gives me an error:

```
$voter = $this->getMockForAbstractClass('Voter', array(), '', true, true, true, array('__call'));

$voter->expects($this->any())
      ->method('something')
      ->will($this->returnValue(true));

$voter->expects($this->at(0))
      ->method('__call')
      ->with($this->equalTo('voteFoo'));

$voter->expects($this->at(1))
      ->method('__call')
      ->with($this->equalTo('voteBar'));

$voter->vote();

*********** ERROR *************
Expectation failed for method name is equal to <string:__call> when invoked at
sequence index 0.
Mocked method does not exist.
```

**Edit**:

If I change the values in `$this->at()` to **2** and **3** the test passes, which means that for some reason `$this->something()` also triggers the `__call` method.

This *Voter* class is not my real *Voter* class, it's a simple version for the question. In my real class I can't tell how many times `__call` will be called..

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior with PHP 5.4.9 and PHPUnit 3.7.9.

Comment: You're right. I've created a simple *Voter* class for the question and it didn't produced the error. I've made some more debugging and updated the question with the findings, please have a look :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear from [the docs](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.stubs.examples.StubTest5.php) , but you should be able to use `returnValueMap` for this:

```
$voter->expects($this->any())
      ->method('something')
      ->will($this->returnValue(true));

$argumentMap = array(
    array('voteFoo'),
    array('voteBar')
);

$voter->expects($this->exactly(2))
      ->method('__call')
      ->will($this->returnValueMap($argumentMap));
```

Comment: But that's just setting the values `__call` **will** return, isn't it? How does it test that **voteFoo** and **voteBar** were called?

Comment: Not exactly. It says "expect a call that returns the last value in this array with the arguments of the other members of this array" for each array in `$argumentMap`. A one-element array in `$argumentMap` is apparently taken as meaning a return value of `null`.

That is, it should check that the methods are actually called.

Comment: I'm sorry, I must be missing something. If I change the values in the `$argumentMap` to `voteHi` and `voteBye` the test still passes, so how is this testing that `voteFoo` and `voteBar` actually called?

Comment: because it's testing that `__call` is called with an argument of `voteHi` and `voteBye`, which it would be. I suppose that's not actually testing that they're *called*, but it's fairly safe to assume that `__call` is doing what it should be.

Comment: But it doesn't.. I only changed the $argumentMap to `voteHi`, `voteBye`. The `vote()` function still calls `voteFoo` and `voteBar`, so the test should fail

Comment: I'm afraid I've no idea then. I'm willing to bet that a small amount of diving in PHPUnit's source will allow you to either see a way to do what you want, or see a way to write a small extension that will allow you to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your effort anyway! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is PHPunit bug when all functions calls is counted. Bug is fixed in 3.7 version